# Do multiple templates really require multiple registrations?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

If I have one iOS device and two message templates, do I need to call `NotificationHubClient.CreateAppleTemplateRegistrationAsync` twice, if at some point in the future I want to send instances of either message to the same device?

Once for each message template with the same device token?

Thus, completely denormalized?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use installations instead of registrations so your device could be coupled to multiple templates. Please read more about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: That looks more sensible.